# Possible to Go to Definition without building code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 mainly to read embedded C++ code from a project with an external build system. The project has a complex build process using multiple cmake files and scripts and compilation and linking takes place in command line and I can’t (or its too tiresome) to build it within Visual Studio.

Is it still possible to still use the code navigation features of VS like Go To Definition/Declaration etc. if I cannot build the project? If so how can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: If this project uses CMake as a build system, you can generate a Visual Studio project and then open it. You don't need to build the entire project unless there are some some interesting files that are generated at build-time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, externel build was not helpfull, since MSVC does not explore the `\*.pdb` file - it stores it's intellisense-data inside a file `\*.VC.db` or `\*.VC.opendb`.

For me (using VC 2015) it was helpfull to add the appropriate include-directories (however it took a while to find them and determine the correct order ;-)). After this step the red underlines under the include directive disapeared and code navigation was possible.

Inside of the DEVENV you just right-click your Project in the "ProjectExplorer(Projektmappen-Explorer)"-pane, choose "Properties(Eigenschaften)" and search for "VC+ directories", "include directories(Includeverzeichnisse)" and edit them.

I strongly recommend to rework the include-directories in a text-editor. To do so close your Project, open the `\*.vcproj`/`\*.vcxproj` file in a text editor search the include path and replace it by a relative ones.